Anchor Element invalid in react mui Menu Component
In the below code when I click on the IconButton that is rendered with each item of tree view, I want a menu list to be opened, so I am passing the event object for getting the element reference to act as an anchor for the menu list, but I am getting error saying that the anchorEl provided to the Menu component is invalid
   import {
      Box,
      CircularProgress,
      IconButton,
      Menu,
      MenuItem,
      Paper,
      Typography,
    } from "@mui/material";
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import { listObjects } from "../services/s3Service";
    import { RichTreeView, TreeItem2 } from "@mui/x-tree-view";
    import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
    import {
      faDownload,
      faEllipsis,
      faTrash,
      faTrashCan,
    } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

const MORE_MENU = [
  { label: "Download Source File", icon: faDownload },
  { label: "Download Word File", icon: faDownload }, // Assuming similar icons for example
  { label: "Delete from Model", icon: faTrash },
  { label: "Delete Source File & Model", icon: faTrashCan },
];

function FilesPage() {
  const [treeItems, setTreeItems] = useState([]);
  const [moreMenuAnchor, setMoreMenuAnchor] = useState(null);
  const [selectedItemId, setSelectedItemId] = useState(null); // Track selected item

  useEffect(() => {
    listObjects("/").then((res) => {
      const topicsWithPostFix = res.prefixes;
      const treeItems = topicsWithPostFix.map((topic) => ({
        id: topic.Prefix.split("/")[0],
        label: topic.Prefix.split("/")[0],
        children: [{ id: `${topic.Prefix.split("/")[0]}-loading`, label: "" }],
      }));
      setTreeItems(treeItems);
    });
  }, []);

  const handleItemClick = (e, itemId) => {
    const item = treeItems.find((item) => item.id === itemId);
    listObjects("", `${item.id}/`).then((res) => {
      const files = res.objects.map((file) => ({
        id: file.Key.split("/")[1],
        label: file.Key.split("/")[1],
      }));

      setTreeItems((prevItems) =>
        prevItems.map((prevItem) =>
          prevItem.id === itemId ? { ...prevItem, children: files } : prevItem
        )
      );
    });
  };

  const handleMoreMenu = (e, itemId) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    setSelectedItemId(itemId); // Set selected item ID
    // Log to check the current target
    console.log("Anchor Element:", e.currentTarget);
    setMoreMenuAnchor(e.currentTarget); // Set anchor element
  };

  const handleMoreMenuClose = () => {
    setMoreMenuAnchor(null); // Close menu
  };

  const CustomTreeItem = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    const { id, label, children, ...otherProps } = props;

    const renderLabel = () => (
      <Box display="flex" alignItems="center" justifyContent="space-between">
        {label === "" ? (
          <CircularProgress size={15} sx={{ marginLeft: 1 }} color="primary" />
        ) : (
          <>
            <Typography>{label}</Typography>
            {!children && (
              <Box>
                <IconButton size="small" onClick={(e) => handleMoreMenu(e, id)}>
                  <FontAwesomeIcon
                    fontSize={15}
                    style={{ color: "#503291" }}
                    icon={faEllipsis}
                  />
                </IconButton>
              </Box>
            )}
          </>
        )}
      </Box>
    );

    return (
      <TreeItem2
        ref={ref}
        {...otherProps}
        itemID={id}
        label={renderLabel()}
        children={children}
      />
    );
  });

  return (
    <Paper elevation={3}>
      <Box>
        <RichTreeView
          items={treeItems}
          slots={{ item: CustomTreeItem }}
          onItemClick={(e, itemId) => handleItemClick(e, itemId)}
        />
        <Menu
          anchorEl={moreMenuAnchor}
          open={Boolean(moreMenuAnchor)}
          onClose={handleMoreMenuClose}
          MenuListProps={{
            "aria-labelledby": `more-menu-button-${selectedItemId}`, // Ensure unique ID
          }}
        >
          {MORE_MENU.map((menu) => (
            <MenuItem key={menu.label} onClick={handleMoreMenuClose}>
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                icon={menu.icon}
                style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
              />
              {menu.label}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Menu>
      </Box>
    </Paper>
  );
}

export default FilesPage;

